# Json To jQuery Search

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a json like below

```
[
    {"name":"mynewname", "id" : "t2", "location" : "India"},
    {"name":"mynewname1", "id" : "t21", "location" : "China"},    
]
```

I have many json data like above..

I need to `textbox` to `Search` the above data..

Comment: did you try anything so far? what do you need filtered exactly?

Comment: what have you tried? what are you filter criteria? Do you have any code attempt to show us?

Comment: sorry i dont have that code... its in my home pc

Comment: You should at least have some idea of what you code does...

Comment: i just need a textbox to search the data above

Comment: you mean search the data irrespective of any field in the JSON data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/geektantra/DsF7J/3/

**NOTE:** I am using Regular expressions for doing a full-text search through the JSON. This could affect performance when the size of your JSON data increases.

Comment: it's working in the fiddle - could you provide us with more code so that we may help you better?

Comment: Using the javascript piece of code which has been given as answer in jsfiddle inside the body part of html is not working.I have used that code inside `<script type="text/javascript">.....</script>`,but its not working at all.

Comment: The javascript code must be put inside `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function() { ..... });</script>`. JS Fiddle takes this from the left hand drop-downs. Check the source code of this page view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/geektantra/DsF7J/3/show/ for the working code.

Comment: I have been going all over the internet for something like this. This answer is perfect! Thank you